# Estimates of solution of Elliptic PDE with variable coefficients

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, elliptic-operators

Does anyone know any reference that treats elliptic pdes with smooth variable coefficients (preferably on infinite domains, e.g, $\mathbb{R}^2$) and gives an estimate of the solution in terms of the norms of variable coefficients?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't you find it in Gilbarg-Trudinger?

Comment: I think that Th. 8.8 is (not exactly, but close enough) what I was searching for, Thanks